# Angular.js, ng-style and IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, angularjs

I'm using angular.js to repeat some data. One of bindings calculates x and y coords and set these with the ng-style-binding. This works fine in every browser except IE8. In IE8 it doesn't even seem to run my function.

But if I output it using {{ }} bindings as text it output correctly, but when using an attribute is does not.

My html look like this:

```
<span ng-repeat="obj in item.products" class="product-point" ng-style="getPos(obj.point.x, obj.point.y, index)">
    <img ng-src="Images/add-button.png" width="100%" ng-click="addItemToList(obj.id)"/>
</span>
```

And the getPos function look like this:

```
$scope.getPos=function(x, y) {
    x = (parseFloat(x) * 0.01) * imageSize.width;
    y = (parseFloat(y) * 0.01) * imageSize.height;

    return "left:"+Math.round(x)+"px; " +"top:"+Math.round(y)+"px";
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to work if you return an `object { top: y, left: x }` instead of a string.